# Make .jar executable on Chrubuntu via command

Tags: minecraft

Im running chrubuntu, im trying to run a minecraft jar file via command (as is not possible via properties page) Whatever command Im using its telling me that no such file exists, I think this may be to do with incorrect ownership of the file? Any advice, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The minecraft.jar file is actually just a launcher, it downloads the neccessary files for minecraft and puts them in the .minecraft folder of your home directory. 
I'm also running minecraft in chrubuntu, and it works fine. Looking at the file I downloaded, it is actually called "Minecraft.jar" (capital M), so make sure that your file is actually called "minecraft.jar".

The jar file does not require executable permissions (it only has rw permissions on my system).
Try moving the file to your home folder, make sure that it is called "minecraft.jar", start a new terminal window and run

```
java -jar minecraft.jar
```

If that does not work, make sure that your user owns the file. If your username is "myuser" type

```
sudo chown myuser:myuser minecraft.jar
chmod +r minecraft.jar
```

to make sure that the file is owned my you, and that it is readable.

To make sure that the file is actually there, type

```
ls -la minecraft.jar
```

which would print something like this

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser myuser 280212 mar 15 16:44 minecraft.jar
```

If everything else fails, try downloading the file again. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can change permissions like this.

```
sudo chmod 700 minecraft.jar
```

Than run this with java environment:

```
java -jar minecraft.jar
```

Make sure that you use the right path to `.jar` file. You can always drag and drop (a) file/files into terminal, instead of typing the path.

So in this case type:

```
sudo chmod 700
```

followed by dragging `minecraft.jar` into terminal. Then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: I just tried, its saying cannot access "minecraft.jar" no such file or directory

Comment: @user265958 Are you in the location of the .jar file? Is it called minecraft.jar?

Comment: yes its called minecraft.jar and is on my desktop, so path would be home/myuser/desktop/minecraft.jar?

Comment: @user265958 Yes. Try this command: `sudo chmod 700 ~/Desktop/minecraft.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way:

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER minecraft.jar
chmod +x minecraft.jar
```